# Is it possible to set the indicator on png icon into the tab to highlight the swipe tab in android?

Tags: android

I want to set the indicator on icon to highlight the icon while swiping the swipe tab . just like a facebook android app is using swipe tab . i tried to change the color of the indicator on swipe tab

```
PagerTabStrip pagerTapStrip = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pagerTapStrip.setDrawFullUnderline(true);
pagerTapStrip.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: where did u set the color for the tab

Comment: i just change the theme  of the particular activity in android.manifest file by android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"

Comment: can u publish the XML file of the PagerTabStrip control

Answer (score 0):

> This is my java file

```
public class Demo extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;




    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Schedule", "Attendance", "Bulletin Board" , "Drawer" };
    final int[] ICONS = new int[] {
            R.drawable.index,
            R.drawable.bulletin_board,
            R.drawable.change_password,
            R.drawable.attendance_button_selected

    };


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);

     // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();

    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#207CAF")));
    actionBar.setTitle("GEMS");
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);       

    // Adding Tabs

   /*for (String tab_name : tabs) {

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)

                .setTabListener(this));

    } */
```